# View not reaching the bottom of the device screen using Autoresize Subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a view controller that has a button at the top center, and a view underneath which will have the collectionview inside. I want this collectionview to scroll separately to the top view (so it scrolls underneath that top section).

This works fine but the view with the collectionview doesn't reach the bottom. You can see in the screenshot I gave the superview a red background - the collectionview doesn't reach to the bottom of the view. All the constraints are fine.

It works if I uncheck "Autoresize subviews" in the Interface Builder for the UIView inside the View Controller but this then makes all the cells and any navigation bars I add inside that view 1000px wide. Why is my view being shortened - and how can I get the best of both these scenarios? A View that hits the bottom of the screen and all the cells/navigation bars the width of the view?
[image: The view in question]
[image: View in simulator]

Constraints for the view:
[image: Constraints for the view]

Constraints for the collectionview:
[image: Constraints for the collectionview]

Comment: Using autolayouts?

Comment: yes! Sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Is that tableview or collectionview?

Comment: It is a collectionview, as mentioned

Comment: Please add the constraints you have set so far. a screen shot will do of both View and Collection View.

Comment: Is the collection view being added programmatically?

Comment: Added the constraints @Mr.Bista.

Comment: The collectionview is added in the storyboard @norders

Comment: Any chance of bottom toolbar or tab bar causing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have a tab bar too, and the gap is the exact height of my tab bar.
Anyway I fixed this by putting:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;
```

in `viewDidLoad` method.